# How do I to read and parse a cookie and store the results in Vuex prior to running Vue-Router guards

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm currently using the method described in [Authentication in SPA the Right Way](https://medium.com/@jcbaey/authentication-in-spa-reactjs-and-vuejs-the-right-way-e4a9ac5cd9a3) wherein a JWT header and payload is stored inside a session cookie.  I want to read this cookie, if available, as soon as my SPA loads, even if the user follows a deep link, and construct a `User` object to check his or her permissions against the requested component.

Currently, I'm reading the cookie, initializing `User` and persisting it to my Vuex store in App.vue's `created()` event.  My reasoning here is to ensure `User` is always created, no matter how deeply a user initially accesses the site, without duplicating code.

I've tried placing the logic comparing `User`'s permissions against the components' requirements in Vue-Router's `beforeEnter()` and `beforeRouteEnter()` events, but these seem to fire before App.vue's `created()` (even though the components are children of App.vue) when accessing deep links directly.

### App.vue

```
<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        user: state => state.auth.user
      })
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('auth', [
        'loginFromCookie',
        'logout'
      ])
    },
    created () {
      this.loginFromCookie()
    }
  }
</script>
```

### store/modules/auth.js

```
[...]
const actions = {
  loginFromCookie ({ commit }) {
    if (window.$cookies.isKey('jwt_payload')) {
      console.log('loginFromCookie()')
      const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode')
      const jwtPayload = window.$cookies.get('jwt_payload')
      const decoded = jwtDecode(jwtPayload)
      const user = decoded.sub
      user.isAnon = false
      commit('setUser', user)
    }
  },
}
[...]
```

### routes/index.js

```
[...]
function guardAgainstNotAnon(to, from, next) {
  console.log('\tguardAgainstNotAnon():')
  console.log('\t\tFails because loginFromCookie() has not been called and User is anon.')
  if (store.state.auth.user.isAnon) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({name: 'home'})
  }
}

export default new Router({
  [...]
  routes: [
    [...]
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        console.log('beforeEnter():')
        guardAgainstNotAnon(to, from, next)
      },
      component: LogIn
    },
    [...]
  ]
})
```

### views/LogIn.vue

```
<script>
  import guardAgainstAnon from '../routes'

  export default {
    name: "LogIn",
    data: function () {
      return {
        form: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      loginUser () {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', this.form)
        this.$router.push({name: 'home'})
      }
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      console.log('beforeRouteEnter():')
      try {
        guardAgainstAnon(to, from, next)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log('\t' + err.name)
        console.log('\tloginFromCookie() has not occurred.')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My expectation is that `loginFromCookie()` would be called from App.vue's `created(`) event before routes are evaluated, but that doesn't seem to be the case...

### Console

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
index.js?e26c:36 beforeEnter():
index.js?e26c:14   guardAgainstNotAnon():
index.js?e26c:15     Fails because loginFromCookie() has not been
                     called and User is anon.
LogIn.vue?c40f:42 beforeRouteEnter():
LogIn.vue?c40f:46   TypeError
LogIn.vue?c40f:47     Component does seem to exist at this point.
auth.js?c7d4:31 loginFromCookie()
```

It seems that moving the logic to process any cookies and instantiate `User` might work in Vue-Router's `beforeEach()` event, but aesthetically, this doesn't feel right to me.  Even if this would work, is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: beforeEach() meets your requirements perfectly! Not sure why you are reluctant to use it...

Comment: Thanks, Stu!  Just thought there might be a better way than reloading my store with user data on each route change. If you throw that into an answer below, I’ll accept it!